# Check if a HTML5 video element is playing

Tags: html, video, html5-video

How can I check status of a HTML5 vide element? I need to toggle play/pause the video element.

Comment: a reference video for trying in browser: [video](http://v2v.cc/~j/theora_testsuite/320x240.ogg)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are few methods like below,

```
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 
if (myVideo.paused) {
  myVideo.play(); 
}
else { 
  myVideo.pause(); 
}
```

have a look at complete working example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop).