# detect if specific html5 video is playing

Tags: javascript, html, video, playback, detect

I can't seem to get this to work.
I am trying to detect if an specific html5 video with the id **normalloop1** is playing.

HTML:

```
 <video id="level1" autoplay controls="none" class="normal-video">
 <source class="active" src="videos/intro.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
 <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
 <source src="videos/video2.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
 <source id="normalloop1" class="loop" src="videos/loop1.mp4" 
 type='video/mp4'/>
 </video>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('normalloop1').one('play', function () {
         alert("Test");
     });
 });
```

I assume that the problem might be, that the video with the ID **normalloop1**, is within  which has an id itself.
However, what would be a way around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a HTML5 video element is playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331670/check-if-a-html5-video-element-is-playing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a HTML5 video is playing using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532133/check-if-a-html5-video-is-playing-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#normalloop1').on('play', function () {
         alert("Test");
     });
});
```

Note the `#` that indicates that `normalloop1` is the `id` attribute. Without it, jQuery is looking for a tag named `<normalloop1>`.

Anyway, this code detect the event "start playing", but maybe the video is already playing when the event handler is added, then you can just check if the video is already playing with something like

```
var video = $('#normalloop1').get(0);
if (!video.paused && !video.ended) {

}
```

Comment: I wrote one instead of on, awesome..
However, I am not using jQuery, and it still did not work for some reason.

I think there is an conflict because this id is inside an other id perhaps?

Comment: If you are not using jQuery, what library is using `$` as global variable?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely your JQuery selector. You're going for an ID, so change this line:

```
$('normalloop1').one('play', function () {
```

to this:

```
$('#normalloop1').one('play', function () {
```

Comment: I can't comment on other people's answers yet, so I'm going to have to do it here: one() works here aswell, because it is the same method as on(), except for the fact that the element handler is unbound after the first invocation [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: I am not using jQuery, and it still did not work for some reason. I think there is an conflict because this id is inside an other id perhaps?

Comment: the `.one()` method is a JQuery method though - Javascript alone doesn't feature this. Also, your selector `$('#normalloop1')` is only used in JQuery. So if you're writing JQuery, but you aren't using it, i think i've found your problem ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the `play` event on the video controller and then check which is the [current selected source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentSrc)

Answer (score 0):

I know two years have passed, but I just came across this question looking for another doubt.

I think the selector is wrong. I think you should use `#level1` instead.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#level1').one('play', function () {
         alert("Test");
     });
 });
```